# Django Rest Framework 500 status, but still creates an instance (not-null constraint)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this very weird bug which i cannot debug since a few hours. I keep getting an error on my post request creating an instance of a liked product in database.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "product_id" of relation "ecommerce_like" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (31, null, null).
```

What's weird is that it creates this instance and works perfectly, yet gives status.500 and i have no idea how to remove it.

So i have this model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('ProductInStore', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('product', 'user',)

class ProductInStore(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And the code for creating an instance of Like is like this:

```
class LikeProductApi(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        product = ProductInStore.objects.get(id=product_id)

        if Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, product=product).exists():
            raise ValidationError("This user already likes this product")
        else:
            Like.objects.create(user=self.request.user, product_id=product_id)
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)


class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    product = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ('user', 'product',)
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: `Like.objects.create` and `super().create` will both create objects. The error most likely comes from `super().create`

Comment: Removed the line Like.objects.create, and still the same error

Comment: Yeah then the error comes from `super().create`. It doesn't know where to get `product_id` if you don't pass it in the request data. Maybe delete `super().create` instead? Since you are already creating the `Like` object manually anyway

Comment: Youre right! Omg, thank you, youve saved a few hours of my life. Have a great day!